# GWT Java object as javascript function gives null

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I'm trying to use one javascript function of javascript module of javascript framework we have in company. I'm trying to use it in GWT.

The javascript calling of the method is:

```
commandsModule.get(100,function(fn){ fn(function(){console.log("Command called")}, undefined, 0, 2)}, undefined)
```

now in my Java code I have:

```
commands.get(
            100,
            command -> command.commandLoaded(
                    onSuccess -> log.log("Command called"),
                    onError -> log.log("ERROR CALLING COMMAND 1"), 0, 2),
            onError -> {
                log.log("ERROR CALLING COMMAND 2");
            });
```

where *command* is:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface OnGetCommand {
    void commandLoaded(JsConsumer<WbsiError> onSuccess,
            JsConsumer<WbsiError> onError, int roadSignalIndex,
            int lampState);
}
```

The thing is, that where in Java I have the *command* variable in lambda, I get null in javascript.

I think the problem is I get a "function" *fn* from javascript but it cannot be represented as Java object => hence the null value.

Is there a way this could be done?

Comment: Don't you need to annotate the interface (or method) with `@JsFunction`? (still strange that JS code receives null though).

Comment: Tried the @JsFunction, no change. Yea in developer tools I see in the javascript source code "null.$_nullMethod" even when I try command.toString()

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using? 2.8.0-beta1, the latest snapshot, or some intermediate snapshot?

Comment: I was using 2.8.0 SNAPSHOT, but when beta got released I moved to beta http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0_BETA1. But I'm really not sure if I done the migration correctly. I just replaced the snapshot jars with the new beta jars. Everything is working fine though (I'm using diferent modules of my js framework just fine), except for this.

Comment: JsInterop got a lot of fixes since beta; try a recent snapshot, it might have been fixed since then. RC1 (or beta2) is upcoming.

Comment: Well I was thinking it's more like bad approach from my side, that I need to treat this returned function differently. I can try the SNAPSHOT, but I don't think takt will be the problem.

Comment: Hard to say with only the info you're sharing; for instance it's not really clear what exactly is null rather than a function. Maybe edit your question to add details.